# Azure SaveChanges vs SaveChangesWithRetries

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Looking at examples that people have coded I see a lot of people using SaveChanges and not using SaveChangesWithRetries. I assume SaveChangesWithRetries is the best thing to do so is there any advantage in just using SaveChanges? Also if I do SaveChangesWithRetries is there anything else that I need to configure or should I just go with defaults?

> _LogEntryServiceContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.PreserveChanges;
>   _LogEntryServiceContext.AttachTo("LogEntry",
>   itemToDelete, "*");
>   _LogEntryServiceContext.DeleteObject(itemToDelete);
>   _LogEntryServiceContext.SaveChanges();
>   _LogEntryServiceContext.Detach(itemToDelete);

Thanks,

Mariko

Answer (score 4):

In general I always use SaveChangesWithRetries - but I do also still have to add my own error handling.

Regardless of which you choose, both methods require you to handle very rare issues/problems:

- in the case you are saving multiple changes then you need to work out a strategy for when half the changes fail
- in some rare cases, saves can fail due to connectivity/availability issues
- in some rare cases, saves can appear to fail due to connectivity issues, but may actually have succeeded - and in this case then retries appear to fail.

The good news is that failures are (in my experience) rare. This isn't good news for "transaction critical" type data, however!